# Vibrato practices on Violin

Tags: violin, vibrato

While practicing vibrato (I've just started) I noticed that while vibrating, for example, on the D string with my third finger using the wrist, when I pull back and forth the third finger, while pulling back, it  sleeps on the A string. I tried to vibrate where my third finger moves in such a way that it doesn't lean on to the other string when it's downwards but it doesn't seem to help. So I wanted to ask that is it normal for the vibrating finger to do that?

Comment: Pulling? It's a rolling action, longitudinally along the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it normal for the vibrating finger to do that?

It is never normal to do that regardless of whether you are vibrating or not. You will have to learn to stop doing this when you come to play double stops on none-open strings because if one of your fingers touches the adjacent double-stopped string you get a horrible sound.

When you vibrate you do not move your finger from side-to-side. You try and move it as much as possible in the line of the string.

The only time one finger should touch two strings at the same time is when you are playing a fifth where the same finger is deliberately holding down two strings at the same time.

Comment: I have to disagree a bit. I'm not sure anyone's fingers are so slender that they can place them on a string in first position and not lightly contact either the string above or below. When I need to play a double stop with the higher string being open, I simply place my finger more to the "left" than usual. That said, @Ruchi, it's impossible to know whether your motion is normal or not without seeing it.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Probably not.

Long answer:
No, that's not normal (unless your fingers are very wide or something). For now it's probably not causing you issues, but when you one day need to vibrato a double stop, this will become an issue.

Your problem is most likely caused because your wrist is not straight. In your case, it sounds like you have what my teacher used to call "pizza hand" or the "waiter/waitress"-- make sure your wrist is not touching the neck of your violin, because this will mess up both the sound you produce, and more importantly the angle that your fingers approach the fingerboard at.

If you have your wrist ruler-straight, you shouldn't have this problem with your vibrato. (Although it's hard to say things definitively without seeing your motion, "pizza hand" will definitely cause many issues if you have this issue.)